# How do I change html structure of menu (primary links for example) to my own?

Tags: theming, routes

The default HTML structure of the primary links menu is not what I'd like it to be. How can I override it with my own version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are working with drupal6 and you have basic understanding of variables and arrays. Default html structure of the primary links is formed at different places in drupal. First if you start with the wrapping div id, in your theme's page.tpl.php file where you print $primary_links change it as the following example:

```
 <div id="dk_one">
 <?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' => 'links primary-links dk_two')) ?>
</div>
```

In order to change what is in $primary_links use the following code in template.php file of your theme.

```
    function yourThemeName_links($links, $attributes = array('class' => 'links')) {
  $output = '';

  if (count($links) > 0) {
    $output = '<ul' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';

    $num_links = count($links);
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
      $class = $key;

      // Automatically add a class to each link and also to each LI
      if (isset($link['attributes']) && isset($link['attributes']['class'])) {
        $link['attributes']['class'] .= 'dk_three ' . $key;
      }
      else {
        $link['attributes']['class'] = $key;
      }

      // Add first and last classes to the list of links to help out themers.
      $extra_class = '';
      if ($i == 1) {
        $extra_class .= 'first dk_four ';
      }
      if ($i == $num_links) {
        $extra_class .= 'last dk_five ';
      }
      $output .= '<li ' . drupal_attributes(array('class' => $extra_class . $class)) . '>';

      // Is the title HTML?
      $html = isset($link['html']) && $link['html'];

      // Initialize fragment and query variables.
      $link['query'] = isset($link['query']) ? $link['query'] : NULL;
      $link['fragment'] = isset($link['fragment']) ? $link['fragment'] : NULL;

      if (isset($link['href'])) {
        $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['attributes'], $link['query'], $link['fragment'], FALSE, $html);
      }
      else if ($link['title']) {
        //Some links are actually not links, but we wrap these in <span> for adding title and class attributes
        if (!$html) {
          $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);
        }
        $output .= '<span' . drupal_attributes($link['attributes']) . '>' . $link['title'] . '</span>';
      }

      $i++;
      $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Clear your cache and you will see dk_one dk_two dk_four dk_five  div ids and classes in your html structure of your primary menu. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Actually it turned out the only thing I needed to get rid of was the title, so removed it by pasting <none> tag into the title field of the block. But despite of that your response was very informative and I will definitely use it in my future ramblings :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 7 it can be found at admin/structure/menu/settings and in Drupal 6 it can be found at admin/build/menu/settings

Comment: Sorry, fixed the title - probably was misleading.

Comment: gotcha. Sorry. Misunderstood. Maybe someone will chime in. :)

Comment: Your advice turned useful after all ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could accidentally help.:)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [theme_menu_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/6), [theme_menu_item_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item_link/6) and [theme_menu_item](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item/6). Override these functions in your template.php file.

Comment: settings.php?.. what is this? haven't stumbled upon it until now.

Comment: Theme's function overwrites should go in theme's template.php file. settings.php is for database connection information and other settings of drupal install  so no theme related functions in settings.php

Comment: Do not like to down vote people, please clarify what you've meant here, so that I can up vote you back.

Comment: @dkiscool, you're correct. That was a bit of a brief moment of insanity on my part. I meant template.php not settings.php